# Can I return an HTTP 410 GONE and still serve the page content?

Tags: c#, asp.net

With ASP.NET, can I set `Response.StatusCode` to `(int)HttpStatusCode.Gone` and still serve the rest of the content of the page to the user? It seems the moment I set the `StatusCode` to a `410` the content of the page is removed and replaced with a generic message.

I know that ASP.NET allows me to change the style of the default error pages, but I don't think that's what I want in this case; I don't want the content of this page to be the default for all `410` errors on the website.

Comment: Ok, understood, thank you and agreed - this should just be a comment and have deleted the "answer". For posterity: I wasn't clear on what the goal/intent was and tried to express that based on your post and how [HTTP 410 is defined](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` to avoid these custom errors.

Comment: That looks like that would work, however I'm targetting .NET Framework 2.0, and for some reason `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` requires .NET Framework 3.5+. :(

Comment: Ok never-mind! It would appear `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` IS actually available on `.NET Framework 2.0` (despite what the MSDN page says); that property was added in `.NET 2.0SP1`.

Answer (score 3):

I've achieved this in the past by simply overriding the OnInit method of the Page and forcing it to return the desired HTTP Status Code. I've had to use this technique when creating custom error pages to insure that the proper HTTP Status Code is returned.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Website
{
    public partial class _410 : Page
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.StatusCode = 410;
            Response.Status = "410 Gone";
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```